# fetching data from SQL based on a given range of dates throwing conversion error

Tags: sql-server

In my application i am trying to fetch data from the database where in the records are to be fetched within a given range of dates.

Below given is the query i am using to fetch the data and the error i am getting from SQL server.

**Query**

```
select * from table_name 
where RequestCreatedOn BETWEEN '31-08-2015 12:00:00.000' and '15-09-2015 12:00:00.000'
```

**Error**

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The values in the table are as follows :

[image]

The datatype of the column is varchar.
I tried many solutions but could not find any relevant answer. Please if anybody could help me with this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Nothing special when you store dates as NVARCHAR. Convert to DATETIME  and use proper `DATEFORMAT`.

Comment: Your convertion tries to convert 31-08 as 31 month 08 date - this causes the error

Comment: when passing dates always use `yyyy-MM-dd` format - it removes any ambiguity between formats. Also, store dates in date fields, not varchar fields.

Comment: @Shivani you need to go into your database **right now** and change the datatype from `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use convertion before comparison:

```
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE RequestCreatedOn BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '31-08-2015 12:00:00.000',105) 
      AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '15-09-2015 12:00:00.000',105)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that your SQL Server is using US dates m/d/y. You should use the standard format yyyy-mm-dd which should always be valid.

So for your query try:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where CAST(RequestCreatedOn as DateTime) BETWEEN '2015-08-31 12:00:00.000' AND '2015-09-15 12:00:00.000'
```

You should also use the most appropriate data type o I would be tempted to change the datatype in your table to datetime.